# How does the Armour of a unit effect the Damage done to it? (Starcraft 1)

Tags: starcraft

In some games, the amount of damage done to your units / you is damage - armour, while in others it can be more complex, such as damage - (damage* armour as a percent)

Where does Starcraft 1 stand on this?

If my unit now has +1 armour because I researched Zerg Carapace, is it a straight -1 damage, or some other calculation?

On a side note, what about the Protoss Shield upgrade, is that like a second armor, just applied to shields?

Comment: Tht is exactly what it means. +1 armour = -1 damage. With a minimum damage of 1 iirc

Comment: ah ok thanks, and im guessing the Protoss Shield is the same, just applied only to damage done to their shields. If you put that as the answer ill tick it thanks

Comment: That being said however, shield doesn't take into account the size of the unit and the type of damage being dealt to it, whereas armour does. I am not sure whether the armour is deducted after the size is taken into consideration or not. Maybe someone else can give you a definite answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each armor reduces the incoming damage by one, prior to any reductions. Then damage reductions are applied due to damage type and unit size. The minimum damage that can be done is 0.5 per attack.

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Damage